# Slow operations on multithreading

Tags: multithreading, node.js, macos, performance, multiprocessing

I am implementing a parallel NodeJS application to compute spatial joins. I am running on a MacBook pro i7 processor with 4 cores (8 after hyperthreading).

To make a fair comparison, I am running exact same operation on all threads. I am attaching activity monitor screenshots for the reference.

**One process**

Completion time: 11.25 seconds

[image]

**Two processes**

Max completion time: 11.53 seconds

[image]

**Four processes**

Max completion time: 14.08 seconds

[image]

**Eight processes**

Max completion time: 24.98 seconds

[image]

My question is, given that in none of the cases memory is full, why does it take such a huge 
performance hit for extra spawned processes when technically it is equipped to run 8 processes independently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code maybe? Anyway, Node.js is not intended for CPU intensive work and it is stated clearly in the description so maybe you should rethink your logic if this is going to be used in some production.

Comment: How is it context switching if it is happening on multiple CPUs?

Comment: Yes, it'd more helpful if the code was posted.

Comment: The code is spanning multiple files. I am trying to write simple code to replicate the problem.

Comment: @William Andrew Montgomery does that mean I should not exceed number of processes more than physical cores?